# subwfb in PIC 18F8722 Assembly

Tags: assembly, pic, mplab

I have a variable temp2 which is assigned 00001101(13) and I had moved 00001010(10) to wreg. (By the way all these registers are checked in MPLAB x Debugger session step by step.) Then, I execute

```
subwfb temp2
```

instruction. temp2 should be 00000011(3) but it is 00000010(2).
What is the problem here, why temp2 is not as expected? Please, some help!

Comment: `b` means borrow. Is looks like you have `CF` when performing `subwfb`.

Comment: Ok, I corrected adding an instruction  "bsf STATUS,0" before subwfb instruction. Is this approach valid?

Comment: I'd say that using `subwf` is better, as it doesn't require additional instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subwfb` instruction subtracts the W register and the borrow (`1` if `C` is set, `0` otherwise) from register `f`. Borrow is used when you do chained subtractions, e.g. when performing subtractions on numbers contained in more than one byte. It is produced by the instructions of form `subXX` and `subXXb` when an overflow occurs.

Example:

```
; let num1, num2 be labels of bytes in a 16-bit number
movlw k
subwf num1
movlw l
subwfb num2

; num2:num1 now contains: the num2:num1 - l:k where num2 and l are upper bytes of a 16-bit number
```

To avoid this behavior when not desired, you can use either `bsf STATUS, 0` or `subwf` (notice the absence of the `b` suffix). Note that using the instruction without `b` (or `c` in the case of addition instructions) when not needed may lead to marginally better performance on some models.